# RealURL was not able to find the root page id for the domain "xyz.com"

Tags: typo3, realurl

i get the error :

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1420480928: RealURL was not able to find the root page id for the domain "www.xyz.com" as there was more than one root page with this domain.
```

in TYPO3 error logfiles from diffrent domains that aren't present on my server. Is there a way to exclude different domains from my TYPO3 instance so those errors dont occure again?

Kind regards
Tomas

Answer (score 2):

This is not a TYPO3 error, but a wrong configuration of the webserver. You should not target domains to your website if it does not handle them.
So either create redirects for those domains and send them to a configured domain or create a domain record for all those domains.

Comment: Those are foreign domains that are not handled by me.

Comment: Still, configure your webserver (vhost) to not route them your TYPO3 instance, but to some other vhost or let it respond with a 404 page.